# I tried to print data from text file into seperate columns

Tags: java, file, file-handling

I want the data to be printed into 20 columns with 20 rows. I created a collection(lines) that contains the data.
I wrote the following code. I am getting index out of bounds error.
**Rows may differ for different columns.......**
**ThankYou**

```
private static void testData(ArrayList<String> lines,ArrayList<Integer> uid) {
    int i=0,start=0,count=0,a=0,b=0;
    int array_of_index[]=arrData(uid); //Function to convert to Array
    while(i<lines.size()){
        if(b==array_of_index.length){
            count++;
            b=0;a=0;
            System.out.println();
        }
        start=array_of_index[a+count];
        System.out.print(Integer.parseInt(lines.get(start))+"\t");
        a=array_of_index[b+1];
        b++;i++;
    }
    System.out.println("SUCCESS");
}
```

Comment: See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Comment: what line is throwing the exception? have you tried debugging?

Comment: @ingrid.e **start=array_of_index[a+count];** is showing index out of bounds

Comment: I'd try using what @JJF suggested but I think your problem has to do with  a=array_of_index[b+1]; which prolly gives a value larger than your array_of_index. You need to check your indexes there.